# AngularFire push function

Tags: javascript, firebase, angularfire2

I am using angularfire as below:

```
 this.afDB.list('/items/' + this.itemID).push({displayName: item.name});
```

The structure then looks like this where the `itemID` is `qoieke`

```
items:
    - qoieke:
            - Leow9dnfwoierjhwelo
                                - displayName: "Something"
```

What I don't understand is how do I avoid getting the `"Leow9dnfwoierjhwelo"` as automatically generated id?

So, I want to have structure like below:

```
items:
    - qoieke:
           - displayName: "Something"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `push` generates a so-called push ID. To not generate that, don't call push. Instead call `set()` (to replace the current values at the location with whatever you pass in) or `update()` (to only modify the properties you pass in).

In your case an `update()` seems to do what you want:

```
this.afDB.list('/items/' + this.itemID).update({displayName: item.name});
```